# Why was my more substantial edit rejected in favor of a subsequent edit?

Tags: support, edits, rejected-edits

The recently made edit was rejected, and now worsens my ratio of accepted to rejected edits. I also believe the subsequent edit to be slightly less substantial, as it ignores some minor issues that were addressed in my edit. I don't understand why this applies towards my count of rejected edits.

My edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11882906

Subsequent edit: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36397449/revisions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rejecting an edit because it conflicted with a subsequent edit happens automatically. When someone with full edit privileges edits a post while your edit is still pending, your edit gets automatically rejected as "Conflicting with a subsequent edit".

Keep in mind this will **not** count against you in the automated edit-ban heuristics.

Comment: Just a clarification: users with full editing privileges can't submit an edit while another one is pending validation. Conflicts only happen when two people edit the same post at the same time, but the user with full editing privileges submits his edit *after* the other user.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski thats only partially true. You can still edit using the edit link after another edit has been proposed. Just the "edit(1)" link will link to the Suggested edit review instead.

Comment: Yes, what I meant to say is that a user with full edit privileges cannot purposefully cause an edit conflict. He can, of course, *improve* or *reject and edit* a proposed edit.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Yes you can. You can manually append `/edit/` to the question link or answer link to open the normal edit GUI.

Comment: Don't say that out loud ;-) Ok, most people *won't* do that on purpose, if you prefer ;)